# Background fetch not updating UI

Tags: objective-c, ios7, appdelegate

I'm new to ios7 background fetch. Here is how I'm doing it.

This is what is going on in `appDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://sample.com/api/home/lastnews"];
OldJson = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

Note that here I'm storing the whole JSON file in a string so i can use to check for new content.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
//HomepageView is the view controller that is supposed to be updated
HomepageView *homepage = [[HomepageView alloc] init];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://sample.com/api/home/lastnews"];
NewJson = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
        return;
    }

    if (![NewJson isEqualToString:OldJson])
    {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
        NSLog(@"New Data : %@",NewJson);
    }
    else
    {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
        NSLog(@"Old Json : %@",OldJson);
    }
}];

// Start the task
[task resume];
}
```

Now to test the whole process, i simply run the application. Then i send it to background and then when i have new content in the JSON file, i use the Simulate Background Fetch operation from the Debug menu. Then i open the application but nothing has changed.

Comment: what do you get in your completion handler ?

Comment: One thing: Only the main thread can modify UI.

Comment: @CW0007007 What do u mean?

Comment: @Larme Ok so does that mean i cannot update the UI in appdelegate? then whats the point of background fetch?

Comment: You can get the data with background fetch and notify a handler on the main thread it needs to update. There's a few ways to do it, I like doing it with NSNotificationCenter: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: 1. Your session task is not initiating any action that would result in your UI being updated. See Nicholas' link. 2. You're initiating asynchronous `NSURLSessionDataTask`, but not using the `NSData` you received in that completion handler block, but rather using the `NSString` you retrieved synchronously before you even started the session task.

Comment: Also, where are you setting the "old JSON" value? If the app was not running when the background fetch request was initiated and it started you app in background mode, I don't see where you are specifying the old JSON value. I just want to make sure you're not assuming that some old ivar will still be accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store your newJson in `NSUserDefaults` as seen below

```
    if (![NewJson isEqualToString:OldJson])
                       {
                         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                         NSLog(@"New Data : %@",NewJson);
                         NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                         [defaults setObject:NewJson forKey:@"newJson"];

                      }
```

Second in your View Controller add this in the `ViewDidLoad`

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refresh:) name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

Add this to your `viewWillAppear`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self loadData];

}
```

Create the loadData

```
- (void)loadData {
    // contains information the ViewController makes use of

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    textView.text =  [defaults objectForKey:@"newJson"];
}
```

Finally add your action

```
-(IBAction)refresh:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"I ran");
    [self loadData];
}
```

I tested this and it works.

Comment: This is wrong. on iOS9.3 this will cause a warning saying: "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release."

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

1. There's no guarantee that JSON data comes in UTF-8 format. Use [NSData dataWithContensOfURL:...]
2. Never, ever access a URL from the main thread. If the server doesn't respond, your app will be hanging.
3. Really bad: In your background fetch handler, you actually load the URL synchronously. And *then* you create a task to load it again. So you load it actually twice.